# Redirect www to new subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect   www.acme.com to subdomain.acme.com

What I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^http://www.acme.com/(.*)$mysubdomain.acme.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This needs to work for page links with and without 'http://'

Thank you.

EDIT*** adding my complete .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule (.*)\.html $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: And what happens? BTW, you probably need a space after `(.*)`

Comment: Rewrite doesn't work as www.acme.com is not recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(acme\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

This will do permanent redirect of every URI from `www.acme.com` **OR** `acme.com` **to** `subdomain.acme.com`.

Comment: added my complete .htaccess above for your review.  When I click a link with www.acme.com, the expected outcome should be subdomain.acme.com.  However, it currently still take me to www.acme.com

Comment: So essentially at present at present you don't see any change in URL (since `www.acme.com` remains `www.acme.com`)?

Comment: Ok I see one potential issue now. This above answer should be placed rule right below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: Also please let me know if this is Wordpress or some CMS/PHP framework running?

Comment: This particular one is for ModX Evolution 1.7.   I have moved the lines right after baseline and the links still don't redirect.

Also, please reply to my twitter message.  Thank you :)

Comment: Actually I didn't get your twitter message. My twitter id is `@anubhava` Also please make sure that above code is placed in **`DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` of `acme.com` domain**

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.acme.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.acme.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.acme\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://subdomain.acme.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The conditions are: "if the host doesn't match subdomain or is unset." With the acton of: redirect any provided URI to that new Host and preserve the URI.

Comment: Leading slash in `RewriteRule` won't be matched in `.htaccess`

Comment: Oh, I suppose it is tagged .htaccess. Always surprised people use those.